# Rails 4 log all not found requests to the application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging, ruby-on-rails-4, request

What i want  to do is to output without error to log file all requests which basically would cause 404 ? or just log such requests separately ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll be best hooking into the [`config.exceptions_app`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#rails-general-configuration) middleware hook:

> sets the exceptions application invoked by the ShowException
>   middleware when an exception happens. Defaults to
>   ActionDispatch::PublicExceptions.new(Rails.public_path).

--

**exceptions_app**

Having [written a gem about this](https://github.com/richpeck/exception_handler), and there are some really [nice demonstrations](https://gist.github.com/wojtha/8433843) of how it can be used effectively, I'd recommend doing something like this:

```
#config/application.rb
config.exceptions_app = ->(env) { ApplicationController.action(:exception).call(env) }

#app/controllers/application_controller.rb
Class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
   def exception
       # your code here
   end
end
```

I'm not sure how you'd make it conditional (I.E only capturing the "not found" exception), but the above would be a starting point for sure!

Answer (score 1):

If the 404's you are after are caused by missing I will suggest to use `rescue_from`, the code in your application controller will look something like:

```
rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, with: :not_found

def not_found
 # log anything in the request
end
```